# $(this) is looping through everything instead of returning the specific div information?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the p tag in the first div, it console.logs all of the remaining divs gameIds instead of just logging the one that I have clicked on. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, does anyone have any suggestions?

```
getGames().done(function(results){
        $.each(results, function (i, gameData){
            $.each(gameData, function(key, game){

                var gamesHome = game.home_team_division;
                var gamesAway = game.away_team_division;


                if(gamesHome == "NCAA Division I" || gamesAway == "NCAA Division I"){
                    // console.log(this);
                    var gameId = game.id;
                    var homeTeam = game.home_team;
                    var awayTeam = game.away_team;
                    var pointTotal = game.total_points_bet;
                    var gameTime = game.game_time_hour;
                    var gameDate = game.game_time_date;
                    var gameId = game.id;
                    var network = game.broadcast_network;
                    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
                    var hueTwo = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
                    var self = $(this);

                $('.wrapper').append('\
                    <div class="main-wrapper col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">\
                    <div class="game-cards">\
                    <div class="chart-container">\
                    <canvas id="'+ homeTeam +'" width="500" height="500"></canvas>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="right-info">\
                    <h4>' + awayTeam + '<br>' + " @ " + '<br>' + homeTeam +'</h4>\
                    <h5 id="time-channel">'+ gameDate +' @ ' + gameTime  + '<br>' + ' On ' + network +'</h5>\
                    <div class="total-points-live">\
                    <h5>Total Points Bet</h5>\
                    <h5 id="point-total">'+ pointTotal +'</h5>\
                    <p>'+ awayTeam +'</p>\
                    <input class="bet-input" data-team-type="'+ awayTeam +'" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmount" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                    <p>'+ homeTeam +'</p>\
                    <input class="bet-input" data-team-type="'+ homeTeam +'" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmount" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                    <p class="bet-button">Click To Place Bet</p>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    ');

                $('p').click(function(){
                    var self1 = $(this);
                    console.log(gameId);
                    console.log(self1);

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to move your `$('p').click` out of `each` block. Currently, you are binding click event multiple times. Second, you have to modify your `event` handler a little bit, like below.

Also, you need to save `gameId`, somewhere in `p` tag so that it can be retrieved later on.

```
...
<p gameid="' + gameId + '">'+ awayTeam +'</p>\
<input class="bet-input" data-team-type="'+ awayTeam +'" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmount" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
<p gameid="' + gameId + '">'+ homeTeam +'</p>\
...
...
$('.wrapper').on('click', 'p', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var gameId = self.attr('gameid');
    console.log(gameId);
});
```